# Code crashes on 64-bit iOS simulator but not on 32-bit simulator or 64-bit device

Tags: ios, 64-bit

I have this code:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getAttributesDictionary:(BOOL)privateKey{
    NSMutableDictionary * query = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    CFTypeRef tag = (__bridge CFTypeRef)((privateKey) ? [self privKeyTag] : [self pubKeyTag]);
    NSLog(@"Tag: %@",tag);
    [query setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    //This is where the crash happens...
    [query setObject:(__bridge id)(tag) forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

    [query setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
    return query;
}
```

When running it on my iPhone 5S (64-bit) or in a 32-bit simulator, it works fine. However if I run it on the 64-bit simulator, it crashes with the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT).

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You're probably doing something nasty like trying to store 64 bit addresses in 32 bit ints.

Comment: But the code works on a 64-bit device, and I can see no error in the code I supplied. Do you mean that there is an error outside the supplied code that affects the result inside? The functions [self privKeyTag] and [self pubKeyTag] return pure NSData-objects so I can not see the error coming from there.

Comment: The code *appears to work* on a 64-bit device. If you cast a 64 bit address to/from a 32 bit int then it may work *in some cases* (depending on whether the addresses happen to fit in 32 bits). I'm only guessing here, but the the symptoms fit with this kind of bug - it could of course be something entirely different, but all those casts in your code are an immediate code smell.